# form_for method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I read a book called 'Rails 3 in Action' and made two pages: 'index' and 'new', set routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'projects#index'
match '/new', to:'projects#new'
```

and projects_controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.new(parmas[:project])
  @project.save
  flash[:notice] = "Project has been created"
  redirect_to @project
end
```

and view files:

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "new", new_path %>
```

This works correctly, because I end up at `localhost:3000/new`, but the problem is:

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
```

This results in:

> undefined method `projects_path' for #<#:0x416b830>

Where is projects_path? When I print `<%= root_path %>`, I get `/`, but `<%= projects_path %>` gives error undefined method.

How do I define a method `projects_path`? Root is not `projects_path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define resource for project in routes.rb

```
resources :projects
```

This will generate helper `projects_path` and a banch of [others](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: solved problem but undefined method `label=' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x4171608>
where i can define Formbuilder ?

Comment: @ChangJuPark You don't have to "define FormBuilder". You need to use `<%= f.label :my_field %>`. It sounds like you're using `<% label= ... %>` instead, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `match '/new', to:'projects#new'` from `routes.rb` and add this:

```
resources :projects
```

Answer (score 0):

The path used to create new projects is a HTTP post to the index URL of "/projects". You need to specify this route:

```
post "/projects", :controller => "projects", :action => "create", :as => "projects"
```

This will generate a `projects_path`, which is the helper method your `form_for` is looking for.

As others have said, you should probably use `resources :projects` instead. If you're interested in only creating a subset of the [seven RESTful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) created by default, you can use `:only`:

```
resources :projects, :only => %w(index new create)
```