# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `SOMETHING_path' for a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The above error is what I receive when I try to create a new resource for my to do list application. The full error is shown below:

```
Failure/Error: visit new_task_path
ActionView::Template::Error:
undefined method `tasks_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000103d814a0>:0x00000103d805a0>
./app/views/tasks/new.html.erb:1:in   
`_app_views_tasks_new_html_erb__695406873618378309_2179930000'
 # ./spec/features/create_task_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

All I have in my routes file is this line of code.

```
resources :tasks, only: [:new]
```

The link below fixes my problem when I use this line of code for my routes:

```
resources :tasks
```

What I want to know is why that is. For this simple web app, I'm going to only be using :new,:create,:edit, and :destroy. I'm doing Test Driven Developement and I just want to get it right. Also, my error says that there is an undefined method 'tasks_path' but I'm not sure what that refers to. My spec file has the correct abbreviation for the 'new' route. What's going on?

Below is my spec file in case that helps.

```
scenario 'with valid task attributes' do
initial_task_count = Task.count
visit new_task_path
fill_in "Name", with: "Daniel Rubio"
fill_in "Description", with: "Grocery Shopping"
select "2014", from: "Year"
select "May", from: "Month"
select "21", from: "Day"
select "Low", from: "Importance"
click_on "Create Task"
expect(page).to have_content("Grocer Shopping")
expect(Task.count).to eql(initial_task_count + 1)
```

end

[Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980501/form-for-method-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tasks_path` is a named route which happens to refer to the `:index` action (known because of the plural word "tasks" and the lack of a parameter being passed to it. You can see all of the  routes, named routes, and paths that Rails knows about for your app by running `bundle exec rake routes`.

In your case, since you only wanted the `:new` route, the named route should be `new_task_path`.

You may also find more useful information in the [Rails Guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web).

[image: Example Routes]

Comment: Thanks @pdobb for the reply. I already had the new_task_path defined in my spec file as shown in my question post, but you're right, adding the index route fixes my problem even though I don't know why.

Comment: Your view file (`app/views/tasks/new.html.erb`) seems to refer to `tasks_path` on line 1. And I'm not sure if you're thinking about this right yet. When you add a route to the `routes.rb` file that creates a named route that your app can use to refer to that url. So until you had the `:index` action specified in your routes.rb file you didn't have the `tasks_path` named route defined yet. That's why adding it fixed the problem. But if you don't want to specify an index action then just make sure you don't refer to it (i.e. remove the call to `tasks_path` from the view file.

Comment: I understand now, the application route works now. I think I wasn't understanding that my simple form had to be on an initial page(index) in order to go to a new.html page. Appreciate the help.